# An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do the following:

```js
interface Collection {
   foo: string,
   bar: string
}

const patchCollection = (
    collection: Collection, 
    propertyToUpdate: {[key: keyof Collection]: any}
) => {
    // do something here
}
```

The goal would be to have `key: "foo" | "bar"` but I get the following error:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead

But I'm not sure how a mapped object would apply here. Any help? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

The question got close due to similar questions existing. I tried the solutions provided there but I didn't manage to make it work with the **Mapped type**.
However, I was able to solve my issue with The Partial Utility Type (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype )

```js
interface Collection {
   foo: string,
   bar: string
}

const patchCollection = (
    collection: Collection, 
    propertyToUpdate: Partial<Collection>
) => {
    // do something here
}
```

This solves also the issue of having the right value type associated with the right key (which I didn't address previously). I'm not sure if I was using the Mapped and Index types in the wrong way (and if there is a way to achieve it with those), but `Partial` definitely seems like the right approach I should have taken from the beginning.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html): *"Mapped types build on the syntax for index signatures, which are used to declare the types of properties which have not been declared ahead of time."*

Comment: You could use Record:
propertyToUpdate: Record<keyof Collection, any>

Comment: Now that the question is open, perhaps you could shift your answer to the answer section.

Answer (score 14):

Use a mapped type (notice the `in` keyword)

```
interface Collection {
   foo: string,
   bar: string
}

const patchCollection = (
    collection: Collection, 
    propertyToUpdate: { [key in keyof Collection]: Collection[key] } // <--
) => {
    // do something here
}
```

A mapped type is a generic type which uses a union of PropertyKeys (frequently created via a keyof) to iterate through keys to create a type.

docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

**edit:**

As the OP mentioned, this seems like a good usecase for the `Partial` utility type as well.

```
const patchCollection = (
    collection: Collection, 
    propertyToUpdate: Partial<Collection> // <--
) => {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Also instead of `{[key in keyof Collection]: any}` you can use `Record<keyof Collection, any>`